# Merge docx files into one and retain numbered list formatting

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk, numbered-list

I have single page input docx template files that user's design to use certain variables such as contact_name.  During processing using the OpenXml SDK + Open-Xml-PowerTools I create many instances of docx files based on this template and substitute in real values for variables.  At the end I need one docx output so I use Open-Xml-PowerTools DocumentBuilder to merge into one docx.

This appeared to work until a user put a numbered list into the template.  My original problem was numbered lists continued the numbering across document instances post merge i.e. the numbers on the second page on the list were 11-20 instead of 1-10 because the document thought they all referred to the same list id.

I managed to solve this by ensuring the num id's were unique in the document body but now the formatting of the list is lost beyond the first page e.g. on the first page the numbered list items are indented but on the second onwards they are hard left on the page like they are not a proper numbered list.  It seems like I need to update the styling and numbering sections to have these matching new num ids but I cannot get this working.

I posted about this on the forums on ericwhite.com but haven't heard back about the latest problem (http://ericwhite.com/blog/forums/topic/list-numbering-on-merged-docs/).

My latest attempt to fix this is throwing an exception inside OpenXml-Power-Tools so I think I am missing updating some section with the new list ids.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Code attempt below with exception following.

```
public bool Merge(List<InterchangeableWordProcessingDocument> inputFiles, string outputFilePath)
    {
        if (inputFiles == null)
        {
            logger.LogDebug("No files to merge.");
            return true;
        }
        try
        {

            List<OpenXmlPowerTools.Source> sources = new List<OpenXmlPowerTools.Source>();
            int highestListNumbering = 0;
            int highestAbstractListNumbering = 0;
            foreach (var inputFile in inputFiles)
            {
                //Sometimes merge puts start of next page onto end of previous one so prevent
                //Seems to cause extra blank page when there are labels so don't do on labels pages
                if (inputFile.DocType == DocType.Letter)
                {
                    using (var wordDoc = inputFile.GetAsWordProcessingDocument())
                    {
                        var para = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements.First<Paragraph>();

                        if (para.ParagraphProperties == null)
                        {
                            para.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
                        }

                        para.ParagraphProperties.PageBreakBefore = new PageBreakBefore();

                        //http://ericwhite.com/blog/forums/topic/list-numbering-on-merged-docs/
                        //Numberings should be unique to each page otherwise they continue from the previous
                        //Keep track of how many we have so we can add on to always have a unique number
                        var numIds = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<NumberingId>().ToList();

                        logger.LogDebug("Found " + numIds.Count + " num ids.");

                        foreach (var numId in numIds)
                            numId.Val += highestListNumbering;

                        var styleNumIds = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.RootElement.Descendants<NumberingId>().ToList();

                        if (wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart != null)
                        {

                            logger.LogDebug("Found " + styleNumIds.Count + " stlye num ids.");
                            foreach (var styleNumId in styleNumIds)
                                styleNumId.Val += highestListNumbering;
                        }

                        if (wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart != null)
                        {

                            var numberingNumIds = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.Descendants<NumberingInstance>().ToList();

                            logger.LogDebug("Found " + numberingNumIds.Count + " numbering num ids.");
                            foreach (var numberingNumId in numberingNumIds)
                            {
                                numberingNumId.NumberID += highestListNumbering;
                                numberingNumId.AbstractNumId.Val += highestAbstractListNumbering;
                            }

                            var abstractNumberingNumIds = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.Descendants<AbstractNumId>().ToList();

                            logger.LogDebug("Found " + abstractNumberingNumIds.Count + " abstract num ids." + wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.XName.LocalName);
                            foreach (var abstractNumberingNumId in abstractNumberingNumIds)
                                abstractNumberingNumId.Val += highestAbstractListNumbering;

                            //Keep the max nums up to date
                            if (abstractNumberingNumIds.Count > 0)
                                highestAbstractListNumbering = Math.Max(highestAbstractListNumbering, abstractNumberingNumIds.Max(ln => (ln.Val.HasValue ? ln.Val.Value : 0)));

                        }


                        if (numIds.Count > 0)
                            highestListNumbering = Math.Max(highestListNumbering, numIds.Max(ln => (ln.Val.HasValue ? ln.Val.Value : 0)));



                        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                    }
                }
                sources.Add(new OpenXmlPowerTools.Source(inputFile.GetAsWmlDocument(), true));

            }
            DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, outputFilePath);
            return true;

        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("Error occured while generating bereavement letters. ", ex);

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var inputFile in inputFiles)
            {
                inputFile.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.DocumentBuilder.CopyNumbering(WordprocessingDocument sourceDocument, WordprocessingDocument newDocument, IEnumerable1 newContent, List1 images)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.DocumentBuilder.AppendDocument(WordprocessingDocument sourceDocument, WordprocessingDocument newDocument, List1 newContent, Boolean keepSection, String insertId, List1 images)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(List`1 sources, WordprocessingDocument output)
at OpenXmlPowerTools.DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(List`1 sources, String fileName)
at BereavementMailing.TemplateEngine.Merge(List`1 inputFiles, String outputFilePath) in C:\caw\Underdog\Apps\Services\BereavementMailingEngine\BM_RequestProcessor\TemplateEngine.cs:line 508
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're updating the same AbstractNumId reference values two times during each pass. You instead need to update the AbstractNum definition id value.

The reference values in your NumberingPart XML look like this:

```
    <w:num w:numId="58">
        <w:abstractNumId w:val="2"/>
    </w:num>
```

and you are updating those twice.

The abstractNumber definitions look like this:

```
<w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="0"
               w15:restartNumberingAfterBreak="0">
    <w:nsid w:val="FFFFFF88"/>
    <w:multiLevelType w:val="singleLevel"/>
    <w:tmpl w:val="8EE6963C"/>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
        <w:start w:val="1"/>
        <w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListNumber"/>
        <w:lvlText w:val="%1."/>
        <w:lvlJc w:val="left"/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:tabs>
                <w:tab w:val="num"
                       w:pos="360"/>
            </w:tabs>
            <w:ind w:left="360"
                   w:hanging="360"/>
        </w:pPr>
    </w:lvl>
</w:abstractNum>
```

Try changing this section:

**Original**

```
var abstractNumberingNumIds = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.Descendants<AbstractNumId>().ToList();

logger.LogDebug("Found " + abstractNumberingNumIds.Count + " abstract num ids." + wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.XName.LocalName);
foreach (var abstractNumberingNumId in abstractNumberingNumIds)
abstractNumberingNumId.Val += highestAbstractListNumbering;

//Keep the max nums up to date
if (abstractNumberingNumIds.Count > 0)
    highestAbstractListNumbering = Math.Max(highestAbstractListNumbering, abstractNumberingNumIds.Max(ln => (ln.Val.HasValue ? ln.Val.Value : 0)));
```

**New**

```
var abstractNums = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.Descendants<AbstractNum>().ToList();

logger.LogDebug("Found " + abstractNums.Count + " abstract nums." + wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.RootElement.XName.LocalName);
foreach (var abstractNum in abstractNums)
    abstractNum.AbstractNumberId += highestAbstractListNumbering;

//Keep the max nums up to date
if (abstractNums.Count > 0)
    highestAbstractListNumbering = Math.Max(highestAbstractListNumbering, abstractNums.Select(a => a.AbstractNumberId).Max(n => n.HasValue ? n.Value : 0));
```